# Guidance trying to make skinny controllers & fat models in CakePHP

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

I'm new to Cake, and to MVC's in general. I want to establish good habits from the get go. Among the good habits are keeping controllers lean, and making the models fat. But it's a bit of a moving target for a noob like me. If I need to pass info from one model to another, do I just dump all that into the controller? Try to make it work in a model?

Here's an action that is a prime example of the kind of confusion I'm trying to sort out.

Everything *seems* like it should be in the controller, but I'm likely wrong. This action gets a list of members, sends that to a view. In the view I can tick members whose accounts I want "activate." No ACL, just simple auth. I make sure that "sub-admins" only see the users they're allowed to manage by use of a db field, client_id. The two models I'm using are User and Client.

```
public function activate() {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->User->id = $id; //make sure current User is the logged in user
        $currentClient = $this->User->field('client_id'); // get client_id based on logged in user
        $members = $this->User->Client->find('first', array( // find users that have the same client_id
            'conditions' => array('id' => $currentClient),
            'recursive' => 1
        ));
        $this->set('clients', $members); // send the users to the view                  
    } else if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $members = $this->request->data['Members']; // grab players submitted from push form
        $memberIds = array(); // this will hold the selected users
        foreach($members as $a){
            $memberIds[$a['id']] = $a['id']; // loop over user's that were selected
        }
        $usersToActivate = $this->User->find('all', array( //find user records, based on the array of id's
            'conditions' => array(
                "User.id" => $memberIds
            )
        ));
        $this->Ticket->bulkActivate($usersToActivate); // send array of members into model for processing
        $this->Session->setFlash('Activations sent.', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

To my eye, it doesn't look drastically wrong... and I'm already doing some processing in the model (as seen with the bulkActivate that actually takes the user records, and generates activation tickets).

But I can't help but feel that it's not quite 100% yet.

Comment: There was a joke in there... and you found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you want to get only ONE client?

```
$members = $this->User->Client->find('first', array
```

I guess this should find all. I've improved this to use pagination in the case there are lots of users. I might be wrong with this but neither your associations nor the real goal is clear to me by looking at this code. I don't know how for example the Ticket model is associated with any other data. But I guess you're using Controller::uses, you should not do that but access related models through their associations.

Do not use horrible variable names like $a, that just sucks and nobody will ever know what that means in a larger code block or application. You also named an array containing client data $members, why not $clients? Read this: [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and for CakePHP I suggest you to follow the [CakePHP coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html).

Describe the goal and this could be refactored even better I think. If you want to activate clients to have access to a ticket (thats what it looks like) why have you not done it in the ticket or client controller/model?

Also this huge amount of inline comments is just causing more mess than it helps. Write clean and readable code and the code will speak for itself. You have not done any super complex code or super complex math there. Again, I can just recomment you to read "Clean Code", it is in my opinion a "must read" for every developer.

```
<?php
    // UsersController.php
    public function activate() {
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->User->activate($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Activations sent.', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

        this->Paginator->settings['Client'] = array(
            'conditions' => array('id' => $this->Auth->('current_id')),
            'contain' => array(
                'OnlyModelsYouNeedHere'));
        $this->set('clients', $this->Paginator->paginate($this->User->Client)); 
    }
?>

<?php
    // User.php - the model
    public function activate($data) {
        $memberIds = array();
        foreach($data['Members']members as $member) {
            $memberIds[$member['id']] = $member['id'];
        }
        $usersToActivate = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id' => $memberIds)));
        return $this->Ticket->bulkActivate($usersToActivate);
    }
?>
```

Passing the ids could be also trimmed down more, but hey, its late here now. :) Take this as a rough refactor of your code and think about what I have changed and more important why.

If you want to see proper examples of skinny controllers and fat models [check our plugins](https://github.com/cakedc/) out, the users plugins UsersController and Model might give you a bigger picture.

Comment: Thanks for that! You are right, I'm using $uses for the tickets, not associations... I thought that might be a bit too much of a cheat. I added comment for SO, but I agree: good code is self commenting. And I only needed to find one client because I'm only looking for records that belong to a given client, never multiples. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Cake will autoload models as needed but with "uses" you'll load them even if not needed at this moment. Would you mind to flag the answer  as correct if you think I'm right? Thanks! ;)

Comment: Of course! Just wondering, why did you suggest using the Paginator? Also, my assumption is that if I had the Ticket model associated with my User model, I can simply do $this->Ticket from inside my User model?

Comment: I explained why I suggest it: I don't know your app and can't guess how many users you'll have. So if you don't want to show 1000 users on a page use pagination, if not simply change the code to use find('all'); You can then get even more code into the model. If Ticket is associated with User you can. Read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html You can go as deep as you want through the association chain.