# Best practice (fat model, skinny controller)

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have a question about the best practice of the following thing:

I have the Model Server (belongs to the User) and the User Model (hasOne Server)

In ClientsController I have user ID from **Auth**.. and I have a method (`getInfo()`) in the Model Server that uses `$this->find()` to get information on a server..

so, the question is what is the best pratice below in **ClientsController** (pseudo-code, ignore it):

```
$intUser = $this->Auth('User.id');
$intServer = $this->Server->getUserOwnerID($intUser); //I get the Server ID respective to that User
$this->set('server_info', $this->Server->getInfo($intServer));
```

or

```
$intUser = $this->Auth('User.id');
$this->set('server_info', $this->Server->getInfo($intUser));
```

In first pratice, getInfo method would have less job, and I could to reuse the function

In second pratice, getInfo method would have the job to get the respective Server from that User ID.. and if I want to reuse without using User ID?

So, what is the pratice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guidance trying to make skinny controllers & fat models in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343141/guidance-trying-to-make-skinny-controllers-fat-models-in-cakephp)

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your question:**

Option #2 seems the clear choice.

In Option #1, you're running 2 methods that will, in total, only need to do a single `find()`.

---

**Even better:**

Or, you could change it to a single line:

```
$this->set('serverInfo', $this->Server->findByUserId($this->Auth('User.id')));
```

Note 1: notice 'serverInfo' being camelCase to follow CakePHP conventions

Note 2: you can use `findBy___` and add a camelCase field-name to automatically do the find.  [See details on 'findBy'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby).

Comment: Ok, what if I have `isOnline` method that sometimes I will have only the User ID and sometimes only Server ID?

Comment: This is starting to feel like 20 questions.  In general, try to keep your Controllers having one-liners, and do the mass of the logic in the Model.  But - only when it makes sense and groups in logical chunks of logic.